# extracting string

Tags: android, string, substring

I would like to find out if I have the following string:

12_123_4_5678_ans123

I know that if you know the start and end indices, you can use:

```
String substr=mysourcestring.subString(startIndex,endIndex);
```

If you want to get substring from specific index till end you can use:

```
String substr=mysourcestring.subString(startIndex);
```

If you want to get substring from specific character till end you can use:

```
String substr=mysourcestring.subString(mysourcestring.indexOf("yourCharacter"));
```

How could it be written for the above if the above is actually 4 choices (each choices can be of different length), extracting 12, 123, 4, 5678 and answer=123?

The common interval would be "_" and the answer must have "ans" before it.

Comment: How about `.subString(str.indexOf("ans") + ("ans").length)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it looks like you are useing a String as an array. This is typically an antipattern and should be avoided. Im not sure where this string is coming from but ask yourself if you cant set things up so that you pass this information around like this rather then in a string.

```
String []  values = new String {
   "12",
   "123",
   "4",
   "5678",
   "ans123"
}; //here the 'ans' would always be the last index, obviously tailor your array to be whats 
   // mosts convienent for you.
```

Im going on a huge limb an guess thess are choices and the answer to a mulitple choice question?
in which case you might want an array of poosible answers and a index store pointed to which is the answer...

```
 String []  values = new String {
   "12",
   "123",
   "4",
   "5678"
};
int correctAnsIndex = 1;
int userAnsIndex = 2;
String correctAns = values[ansIndex];
booelan isCorrect = (userAnsIndex == correctAnsIndex);
ect, ect, ect...
```

If you cant change this, a hacky solution would be the split command. 
`"12_123_4_5678_ans123".split("_");` will return and array like this 
{"12","123","4","5678","ans123"};

getting the answer would look like this...

```
String [] values = "12_123_4_5678_ans123".split("_"); 
String answer = null; 
for(String s : values  ) {
    if( s.startsWith("ans")){
        answer = s; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: How is it an antipattern? If you don't wan't to serialize the data and would prefer a straight text file for essentially all your apps data, this is fine. I agree, it would be a hassle to change and there are definitely better ways to do it (database, xml, json) this works perfectly for the problem presented.

Comment: You should serialize. What valid reason do you have to not want to serailize? Straight text files are larger, slower to read for the computer, and if the data has any kind of structure harder to debug. Plus he is storing data in ways that aren't 'self-documenting' which can only introduce errors.

Comment: Raw text and serialized text is the same size; based its encoding. It's harder to change on the fly and harder to write (than just `String.split("")`). All changes to a question sampling will need to be reserialized, where as a text file can be plug and play.

Comment: Its not the same size if you have any data that is not string. '65526' to '8000' in binary encoded form.  Plus to get back you dont have to do pointless stoi conversion. The second one is clearly smaller. Plus you only support the most naive data this way. And creating a lot of extra work. It should be SavedInfo si = new SavedInfo(); where SavedInfo implements Externalizeable. `File f = sf.save();` and `SavedInfo loadedInfo = f.load();`. The interface will do all the work and abstract it away form the actualy program logic. All around it makes for more stable, clean effiecnt and robust code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the String class split method instead. If you always want to split on "_". This will split you string into a array of string instances, using a delimiter of your choice.

```
String mystring = "test_12_woop_11";
String results[] = mystring.split("_");
```

Answer (score 1):

As @JustDanyul and I previously stated `String.split("_");` will do the trick. Now to parse our answer, just do something like this:

```
String[] data = "12_2345_3465_312_ans12".split("_");
String answer = null;
for (String s : data) {
    if (s.startsWith("ans")) {
        answer = s
        break;
    }
}
```